# how to run powershell script command in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I want to run powershell script from asp.net page. Here the script

when i run this script i received the below error. 
"The name 'PowerShell' does not exist in the current". Check this code and provide solution..

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace Poweshellproject
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clean the Result TextBox
            ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

            // Initialize PowerShell engine
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();

            // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            shell.Commands.AddScript(PowerShellCodeBox.Text);

            // Execute the script
            var results = shell.Invoke();

            // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
            // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                // We use a string builder ton create our result text
                var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                    // Add \r\n for line breaks
                    builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }

                // Encode the string in HTML (prevent security issue with 'dangerous' caracters like < >
                ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run a powershell script from a web page?  That sounds very dangerous.  It could open your server to all kinds of security issues.

Comment: I want to run some command from a webpage. so that i am using.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - there's no "PowerShell" in the current name context. You probably forgot to import something before trying to initialize a PowerShell object with `PowerShell.Create()`.